# Kotlin super.finalize()

Tags: kotlin, finalize

While migration to `Kotlin` from `Java` I faced with a problem. I overrided `Object`'s `finalize()` method:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    stopTimer();
    super.finalize();
}
```

When I tried to do the same with Kotlin I found to solutions. The first one is from the doc:

```
 protected fun finalize() {
    stopTimer()
    super.finalize()
}
```

And the second one from the [article](http://kotlin.ohandroid.com/finalize.html) (it's in Russian):

```
@Suppress("ProtectedInFinal", "Unused")
protected fun finalize() {
    stopTimer()
    super.finalize()
}
```

But in both cases I can't call `super.finalize()` according to IDE, as it says `unresolved reference:finalize`

Maybe anybody knows how to get this work in `Kotlin`? Thanks.

Comment: Do not call `super.finalize()`. It is not required by Java contract and it is redundant in practice, since `Object.finalize()` is an empty method.

Comment: Since `finalize()` is defined on class `Object` in the JVM, there has to be more to the story. I notice that you have no `override` keyword. Please correct it and try again.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Your advice contradicts the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#finalize).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the contract of `finalize` in Java:

> The finalize method of class Object performs no special action; it simply returns normally. Subclasses of Object may override this definition.

Therefore you are not required to call through to the superclass. You would be calling through to an empty implementation.

The need to call `super.finalize()` arises only in classes not directly deriving from `kotlin.Any`.

The rest of the story is already told in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#finalize): just declare a `protected fun finalize()`.