# calling finalize() of super class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, finalize

I have the following Java code I wanted to convert into Kotlin:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        release();
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

In the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#finalize) I have found this:

```
protected fun finalize() {
    // finalization logic
}
```

I use that like this:

```
protected fun finalize(){
    try{
        release()
    }finally {
        super.finalize()   <--- But Android Studio does not recognize finalize()
    }
}
```

Is it ok when I just delete `super.finalize()`? I have read the following SO threads but could not find a solution:

- [How to implement finalize() in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784161/how-to-implement-finalize-in-kotlin)
- [Kotlin super.finalize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393502/kotlin-super-finalize)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `super.finalize()` method to call because you are subclassing `Any`, not `Object`. `Any` doesn't have a `finalize()` method. You wouldn't need to do this for `Object` in Java either, because the base implementation doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on `finalize` but make your class `AutoCloseable` instead. There is no guarantee your finalize method will be called, it is slow and may introduce security issues. Note `finalize` has been already deprecated in Java9 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

For AutoCloseable, Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Then you'll be able to use `use` in Kotlin:

```
class MyClass: AutoCloseable {
    override fun close() {
        // Release here
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyClass().use {
        // Do the work, close will be called for you
    }
}
```